# I have an int value; now how do I present it in a TextView to the user? Android

Tags: android

Beginning I should say that I am very new to programming.

I am building an android application which includes a calculator function. What I want to do is on button click to get the user input from two EditTexts, add them together and then display the result in a TextView. Similar questions have been covered by others, but what they don't cover is how do you actually display the result in a TextView (or at least I didn't find one myself). So I tried the following which was suggested in many posts:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.team2);

    //finds the references for the view in the layouts
    b_t2p_ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK2);
    EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPaixnidi2);
    EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPontoi2);


    b_t2p_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         //First I am trying to do this for one EditText
            String myEditValue = etPaixnidi20.getText().toString();

            int myEditNum = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);

            myEditNum.setText(textOut);         
        }
        });

}
```

However when I try to display the int myEditNum in a TextView(textOut1) using the setText() method I get an error for the setText method (saying: ''Cannot invoke setText(TextView) on the primitive type int'').

I also tried (below) to convert int myEditNum to a String and then display it to a TextView but still doesn't work as I get the folloing error for the setText method: ''The method setText(TextView) is undefined for the type String''.
EditText myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

```
String myEditValue = myEdit.getText().toString();

int myEditNum = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);


String texting = Integer.toString(myEditNum);

texting.setText(textOut1);
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call *setText(string)* on a Textview. So you can do something like:

```
// Replace R.id.textview1 with the id of your textview
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
tv.setText(myEditValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the wrong variable to settext here. the View class can do setText()

Try:

```
...
public void onClick(View v) 
{

    //First I am trying to do this for one EditText
    String myEditValue = etPaixnidi20.getText().toString();

    EditText1.setText( myEditValue );
    // or
    EditText2.setText( myEditValue );

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
textOut1.setText(texting)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the TextView and the String the wrong way round.

```
textOut1.setText(texting);
```